# How dynamically count progress bar value in background worker?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

How dynamically count progress bar value in backgound worker based on gridview total row count?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BackgroundWorker runs on a thread different from the UI thread. You will therefore get an exception if you attempt to modify any control on the form from within the [DoWork](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.dowork.aspx) event handler method of the background worker.

To update the controls on your form, you have two options:

- Call the [ReportProgress](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) method of the background worker and then handle the [ProgressChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) event.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Public Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
        ' This is not the UI thread.
        ' Trying to update controls here *will* throw an exception!!
        Dim wkr = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
            ' Do something lengthy
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            ' Report the current progress
            wkr.ReportProgress(CInt((i/gv.Rows.Count)*100))
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub bgw_ProgressChanged(sender As Object, e As ProgressChangedEventArgs) Handles bgw.ProgressChanged
        'everything done in this event handler is on the UI thread so it is thread safe

        ' Use the e.ProgressPercentage to get the progress that was reported
        prg.Value = e.ProgressPercentage
    End Sub
End Class
```

- Invoke delegates to perform the updates on your UI thread.

```
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1
    Public Sub bgw_DoWork(sender As Object, e As DoWorkEventArgs) Handles bgw.DoWork
        ' This is not the UI thread.
        ' You *must* invoke a delegate in order to update the UI.
        Dim wkr = DirectCast(sender, BackgroundWorker)

        For i As Integer = 0 To gv.Rows.Count - 1
            ' Do something lengthy
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
            ' Use an anonymous delegate to set the progress value
            prg.Invoke(Sub() prg.Value = CInt((i/gv.Rows.Count)*100))
        Next
    End Sub
End Class
```

**NB:** You can also see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5281422/117870) to a related question for a more detailed example.